# SharePoint 2010 sites are not working after changing computer name

Tags: 2010

I am facing problem in SharePoint. We have total 7 servers in that we made 1 server as domain and placed all the remaining servers into the domain.

In 1 server, we installed Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL server in another server. After installing SharePoint 2010 in Windows Server 2008 R2, we changed our server name from that onwards our SharePoint Central Administration and Sites are not working. So I have changed the server name back and re-configured the SharePoint configuration wizard, after this central administration site started working but sites are not working. So I created new site then also sites are not working.

I am not understanding the problem.

please help me out from this problem.

Comment: The problem is that you should not have renamed the server in the first place. Also, renaming it back won't necessarily work as it uses SID's and not the computer names to identify itself.Sorry, I don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you now got a problem authenticating users in SQL Server. Databases are not reachable and therefore no site access. Try to use Fiddler, ULS-viewer or just the browsers own code debugger to see if you get a warning "access denied to SQL" when opening site.